# When will $A_1^c \Delta A_2^c = (A_1 \Delta A_2)^c$ holds?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I tried many cases but all failed. I thought because $$A_1 \Delta A_2 = A_1^c \Delta A_2^c,$$ so that the question is really asking $$A_1 \Delta A_2 = (A_1 \Delta A_2)^c.$$

Can I say it will never hold because the complement of a set will never equal to itself?

What if there are more than two sets, like $$A_1^c \Delta A_2^c \Delta A_3^c = (A_1 \Delta A_2 \Delta A_3)^c.$$ I'm not sure for this case.

EDIT:

I found that for an odd $n$, $$A_1^c \Delta A_2^c \Delta ... \Delta A_n^c = (A_1 \Delta A_2 \Delta ... \Delta A_n)^c$$
will definitely hold. But still have trouble to formally prove it.

Comment: If you look at the characteristic functions of the sets with values in $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, the matter becomes rather simple. Are you somewhat familiar with the concepts mentioned?

Comment: Sorry this is my first week of discrete mathematics course. I don't know what are you talking about. Can you give me some references about that? I'm interested in your idea.

Comment: For a set $A$, define the characteristic function of $A$ by $$\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, x \in A \\ 0 &, x \notin A.\end{cases}$$ If you let $\chi_A$ have values not in $\mathbb{R}$ but in $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, so that $1+1 = 0$, then you have the very useful relation $\chi_{A\triangle B} = \chi_A + \chi_B$. Since $\chi_{A^c} = 1 - \chi_A = 1+\chi_A$ [since $1+1 = 0$ we have $-1 = +1$], you can easily see how the symmetric difference of $n$ sets is related to the symmetric difference of their complements.

Comment: That's really a lot of information. Thanks! I'm trying to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not $100\%$ sure this is correct. I used some basic identities to get this:

$\begin{align}(A_1 \Delta A_2)^c &= \left((A_1 \setminus A_2) \cup (A_2 \setminus A_1)\right)^c \\
& = (A_1 \setminus A_2)^c \cap (A_2 \setminus A_1)^c \\
& = (A_1 \cap A_2^c)^c \cap (A_2 \cap A_1^c)^c\\
& = (A_1^c \cup A_2) \cap (A_2^c \cup A_1)\\
& = ((A_1^c \cup A_2) \cap (A_2^c)) \cup ((A_1^c \cup A_2) \cap A_1)\\
& = (A_1^c \cap A_2^c) \cup (A_2 \cap A_1)
\end{align}$

$\begin{align} A_1^c \Delta A_2^c & = (A_1^c \setminus A_2^c) \cup (A_2^c \setminus A_1^c) \\
& =  (A_1^c \cap A_2) \cup (A_2^c \cap A_1)\\
\end{align}$ 
\
If $(A_1 \Delta A_2)^c = A_1^c \Delta A_2^c$ that would mean $A_2^c=A_2$ and $A_1^c=A_1$ which is impossible, thus this never holds.

Comment: Hi! Actually for two sets, this equation will never hold. I just ran the code and found that for an odd $n$, this equation will hold. And I'm still working on proof.